# Lost some rep due to a removed user but didn't lose any up-votes

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts

I read several questions and answers regarding reputation loss due to a removed user.
Today I noticed a -5 rep change titled `User was removed`:

[image]

According to what I read, all the reputation gained by a user's up-votes (or lost by down-votes) is cancelled when the user is removed.
Now, a 5 rep loss is quite a minor loss, and I'm not complaining about it. I'm just curious.

Since it's only 5 points, it has to be a cancelled up-vote on a question. Since I only have 6 questions, and only 2 of them ever had votes, I see all my up-voted questions every time I look at my profile. Therefore I know for sure that I had 4 question up-votes. I still do. So if I lost a question up-vote, shouldn't the vote count on one of my question changes?

I further explored the data, using the [reputation log](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation). There I found only 3 of my 4 question up-votes :

> 2  10692736 (5)
>
> 2   9365302 (5)
>
> 2   9365302 (5)

Which means I lost one of the votes for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365302/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-ssl-certificates-for-providers-that-send-apns) (whose Id is 9365302).
However, the vote count of this question still says 3.

[image]

Is it a bug, or will the data refresh eventually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vote counts are cached. When a vote is deleted, it doesn't update the cache.

I just clicked on the vote number to expand it and it now shows 2. (i.e. I forced it to recalculate the vote count)

Comment: In other words, it's always caching.  Needs more jQuery.

Comment: @Robert maybe jCaching!

Comment: And if you're wondering how I know this... It's because I get hit by a lot of user-deletions. So I see this quite often - about twice a month.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks for the quick answer! So, in other related questions I read that we are not supposed to know on which answers/questions we lost votes due to deleted users. It seems that by clicking on the votes of all our posts we can learn just that.

Comment: @Eran Correct, but most people with a lot of posts won't have the patience to do that. :)